# How to prioritize a single item in collection sort order

Tags: magento-1.9, collection

I am working with custom collection that is already sorted. I have to move one item on first place, if it is exist in collection.

```
$id=10;
$collection = Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => '1'));
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(id, ' . implode(',', $ids).')'));
```

How can I modify the sort order so that an item with id 10 will always be at the beginning?

Comment: (but you know that you can sort by multiple expressions? It sounds like you could do this additional sorting in the query with a boolean expression)

Comment: @fschmengler i just read the first comment on your answer `This is a terrible answer. You are doing not one but two foreachs over a collection before loading it. This will take forever for large collections and will decrease performance a lot.` don't want use that

Comment: Please also read the other comments and my disclaimer. (And my comment above. If you provide more details about the item at the beginning, this question can be answered)

Comment: @fschmengler this question is if id `10` exist then move item to first place. not about adding new item. It is totally different question but i cannot question your judgment.

Comment: I tried to clarify the question based on your comments and nominated it for reopening. Hope it matches your intentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> this question is if id 10 exist then move item to first place

Then sort by "is it id 10" first (true > false), then sort by your other expression:

```
$id=10;
$collection = Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection();
$collection->addFieldToFilter('status', array('eq' => '1'));

// ADD THIS:
$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('(id=' . intval($id) . ')'), 'DESC');

$collection->getSelect()->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('FIELD(id, ' . implode(',', $ids).')'));
```

Comment: as i mention in question can't use sort `already sorted`

Comment: you can use "order()" twice. And if you cannot add code before the existing "order()" call, you can still use `getSelect()->reset('order')` and apply the sort orders in the right order again. Or do you mean "already **loaded**"? In this case you must use the method described in the linked duplicate.

Comment: thanks for help got it worked through `array_unshift()`.